# Read two column CSV as dict with 1st column as key

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with two columns, column one is the team dedicated to a particular building in our project.

The second column is the actual building number.

What I am looking for is a dictionary with the first column as the key and the buildings that belong to that team in the list.

I have tried various forms of `csv.reader` and `csv.DictReader` along with different for loops to rewrite the data to another dictionary, but I cannot get the structure I want.

**CSV:**

```
team,bldg,
3,204,
3,250,
3,1437,
2,1440,
1,1450,
```

The structure of the dictionary would be as follows:

```
dict["1"] = ["1450"]
dict["2"] = ["1440"]
dict["3"] = ["204", "250", "1437"]
```

Comment: Does your data have the trailing `,`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
import csv

result={}
with open('/tmp/test.csv','r') as f:
    red=csv.DictReader(f)
    for d in red:
        result.setdefault(d['team'],[]).append(d['bldg'])

#results={'1': ['1450'], '3': ['204', '250', '1437'], '2': ['1440']}
```

Answer (score 2):

The useful `collections.defaultdict` in the standard library makes short work of this task:

```
import csv
import collections as co

dd = co.defaultdict(list)
with open('/path/to/your.csv'),'rb') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    for line in dr:
        dd[line['team']].append(line['bldg'])

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'1': ['1450'], '3': ['204', '250', '1437'], '2': ['1440']})
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

> The first argument provides the initial value for the `default_factory`
>   attribute; it defaults to `None`.